# How to configure java.util.logging in groovy for class/method name?

Tags: logging, groovy, java.util.logging

testlog.java:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class testlog {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(testlog.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format","[%1$tF %1$tT]:%4$s:(%2$s): %5$s%n");
        log.info("logging test");
    }
}
```

execute:

```
$ java testlog
[2014-01-18 11:08:51]:INFO:(testlog main): logging test
```

testlog.groovy:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class testlog {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("testlog");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",'[%1$tF %1$tT]:%4$s:(%2$s): %5$s%n');
        log.info("logging test");
    }
}
```

execute:

```
$ groovy testlog
[2014-01-18 11:11:23]:INFO:(java_util_logging_Logger$info call): logging test
```

How to configure groovy for class/method name instead of "java_util_logging_Logger$info call" ?

Comment: thanks for showing me the format I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Groovy uses [`CallSite`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.html) in bytecode, generally. Groovy code mentioned above would compile to below format of bytecode:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class testlog
  implements GroovyObject
{
  private static final Logger log;

  static
  {
    __$swapInit();long l1 = 0L;__timeStamp__239_neverHappen1390064566496 = l1;
      long l2 = 
        1390064566495L;__timeStamp = l2;
       Object localObject = 
        $getCallSiteArray()
           [2].call(Logger.class, "testlog");log = 
           (Logger)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(localObject, Logger.class);
  }

  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = 
      $getCallSiteArray();arrayOfCallSite[0].call(System.class, 
        "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", 
                  "[%1$tF %1$tT]:%4$s:(%2$s): %5$s%n");
    arrayOfCallSite[1].call(log, "logging test");
  }

  public testlog()
  {
    testlog this;
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
    MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
    this.metaClass = localMetaClass;
  }
}
```

So it refers to the `Log` class when referred from the formatter. To work around with this you can use [`CompileStatic`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html) annotation on class level which converts source to bytecode in normal Java convention.

Here is how the script should look (Note:- Class name is CamelCase):

```
import java.util.logging.Logger
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
public class Testlog {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("testlog")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",
            '[%1$tF %1$tT]:%4$s:(%2$s): %5$s%n')
        log.info("logging test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it works this way... But IMHO it's too much. @CompileStatic not good for me. Tnx, now i understand why it works this way, i will try to write my own Formatter.

Comment: No, I moved from Groovy to Kotlin (https://kotlinlang.org/). Best language atm as for me.