# Logging and accessing variables in Groovy threads

Tags: multithreading, groovy

My question is about Groovy Threads and their correct usage. If I have code that looks like this:

```
BatchJobDetail batchInProgress= batchInProgressService.createNewBatchJob()
SomeService someService = new SomeService();
log.info("Forking thread")
 Thread.start ({
   log.info("Starting export..")
   def exportResults = someService.getExportKeys(params)
   log.info("export done..")
   batchInProgress.isCompleted = true
 })
```

Does my thread always have access to batchInProgress and someService variables?

Also, my logs in the thread do not print in this case. The log outside the thread prints fine.

Any pointers?

Comment: 1) Yes as it's a Closure.  2) How have you set up logging? Do you have an example that sets up `log` for testing?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201305/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-in-groovy-for-class-method-name) is something which I came across recently might help you as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - I had to do some slight adjustments to create some objects but the code below runs 'standalone'

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

class BatchJobDetail {
    boolean isCompleted
}

class BatchInProgressService {

    BatchJobDetail createNewBatchJob() {
        println 'creating a batch job...'
        new BatchJobDetail()
    }

}

class SomeService {
    def getExportKeys(params) {
        return []
    }
}


Logger log = Logger.getLogger("")
log.info ("Log created...")

BatchInProgressService batchInProgressService = new BatchInProgressService()
BatchJobDetail batchInProgress = batchInProgressService.createNewBatchJob()
SomeService someService = new SomeService();
log.info("Forking thread")
 Thread.start ({
   log.info("Starting export..")
   def params = []
   def exportResults = someService.getExportKeys(params)
   log.info("export done..")
   batchInProgress.isCompleted = true
 } )
```

Log statements inside the thread do print. Don't think we ever saw a response to Tim's question about how you are setting up "log".